# How to handle Image sizes on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

Currently, i am doing this type of view, What is the best way so i can manage the image in different size of scale

[image: this one]

We have this sizes,

```
Device          Points    Pixels     Scale  Physical Pixels   Physical PPI  Size
iPhone 6 Plus   736x414   2208x1242  3x     1920x1080         401           5.5"
iPhone 6        667x375   1334x750   2x     1334x750          326           4.7"
iPhone 5        568x320   1136x640   2x     1136x640          326           4.0"
iPhone 4        480x320   960x640    2x     960x640           326           3.5"
iPhone 3GS      480x320   480x320    1x     480x320           163           3.5"
```

**My Problem** is image coming from server i want to handle this image in all type of device of Apple, I am using aspect fit in cell and when i am using 640 * 106 size then in i-phone 6plus this images are are not showing correctly size

**Here's my code**

```
CGRect frameIphone = (flag) ? CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 106):CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 106);

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(iPad) ? CGRectMake(10,8,55,55) : frameIphone];
img.tag = indexPath.section;
img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
img.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[objClass getImageForBackground]] placeholderImage:nil];   // URL Images
```

Comment: Mean your image in server is one size and appear wrongly in 6plus?

Comment: @Tj3n Yes i want is if image comming from server i can show it in all devices if i am using 640 * 106 (iPhone6) size then in iphone5 and iphone6+ images are not fit the screen

Comment: @MayankPatel you can use auto layout then you not need to set image frame .

Comment: @MayankPatel - chek once you retrieve the correct image for e.g 3x size or not

Comment: @balkaransingh already using auto-layout

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  when i tried to use Iphone6plus width * 106 height then in iPhone6 images are cutting from top and bottom due to image scale fit type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not that hard really, because what you doing is fixing the width/height of the view, what you need to do is calculate based on the screen ratio and give it correct height since the width is fixed based on the screen width, example if the screen is iphone 6plus, which have point of `736x414`, and the image is `640x106`, you do a calculation `736*109/640` (screen width * image height / image width, change with variable) = 125, thats the imageView height you should use, not 106 directly

You can set the image to the image view first then config it's frame also ok, so you can get the image height/width

Comment: why i need to calculate height ? i have fixed height so i hardcoded it

Comment: image height and imageView height is different, thats why your image appear wrongly

Comment: Thanks this code works what i did it Screen Width * Image height / Image Width after that it work so am i right ? is it correct as per your way ?

Comment: Yes, just calculate your imageView's height to fit the ratio then the image will fit